# how do i write SQL Query for getting following output from two tables (With Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

table 1:
teacher

```
+------+--------------+
| id   | Teacher_name |
+------+--------------+
| 1    | M       |
| 2    | S        |
+------+--------------+
```

table 2:
Students

```
+------+--------------+
| id   | Subject_name |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | English      |
|    1 | Marathi      |
|    1 | Hindi        |
|    2 | Biology      |
|    2 | Physics      |
|    2 | History      |
+------+--------------+
```

i need output like

```
[
  {
    "Teacher_name": "M",
    "Subjects": [
      {
        "Subject_name": "english"
      },
      {
        "Subject_name": "marathi"
      },
      {
        "Subject_name": "hindi"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Teacher_name": "S",
    "Subjects": [
      {
        "Subject_name": "biology"
      },
      {
        "Subject_name": "physics"
      },
      {
        "Subject_name": "history"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an ID in a sql table that repeats.  The students table, for example, has multiple IDs of 1 and multiple IDs of 2.  You can have a column that is labeled "ID" without it actually being an ID but this amounts to mislabeling, and is confusing for anyone else who ever looks at the table. What is the actual structure of those tables?  In order to create a relationship between those tables, you would need a column in the students table that refers to the teacher since there is a `One to Many` relationship between `Teachers and Students` respectively.  i.e., "A teacher can have many students."

```sql
+------+--------------+
| id   | Subject_name | Teacher
+------+--------------+
|    1 | English      |    1
|    2 | Marathi      |    1
|    3 | Hindi        |    1
|    4 | Biology      |    2
|    5 | Physics      |    2
|    6 | History      |    2
+------+--------------+
```

Then you would use an "inner join" similar to this:

`SELECT Subject_name, Teacher_name FROM Students INNER JOIN teacher ON (teacher.id = Students.teacher);`

This would return:

```sql
+--------------+
| Subject_name | Teacher
+--------------+
| English      |    M
| Marathi      |    M
| Hindi        |    M
| Biology      |    S
| Physics      |    S
| History      |    S
+--------------+
```

Further, the output you need would require digesting the output from that query and then building an object or array with the information. Also there is no field in any of the tables for "Subject_name" so unless you have an alternate data source or another table, this field would have to be basically manually populated.

There appears to also be a `one to many` relationship between teachers and subjects, that is to say... "a teacher can teach many subjects" so you likely need a table like this.

Call the table "Subjects"

```sql
Teacher_name  |  Subject_name
     M        |    english
     M        |    marathi
     M        |    hindi
     S        |    biology
     S        |    physics
     S        |    history
```

The query would then simply be `select * from Subjects;`

Or if you wanted the records to be uniquely identifiable.

```sql
  ID  |  Subject_name  | Teacher
  1   |    english     |    1
  2   |    marathi     |    1
  3   |    hindi       |    1
  4   |    biology     |    2
  5   |    physics     |    2
  6   |    history     |    2
```

Then you would use a similar inner join like:

`SELECT Teacher_name, Subject_name FROM Subjects INNER JOIN teacher ON (teacher.id = Subjects.teacher);`

Would yield the following results:

```sql
 Subject_name  | Teacher
   english     |    M
   marathi     |    M
   hindi       |    M
   biology     |    S
   physics     |    S
   history     |    S
```

The node.js part is just a matter of creating a connection and feeding it the correct sql string.  One example:
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

That all depends on your table structures though.